# Using callouts in Expression Blend + Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, expression-blend

I have an Expression Blend+Silverlight application that makes use of callouts. Now I want to show several strings each after a specified duration within a single callout. But I can't set the ContentProperty of the callout programmatically - it's throwing an exception.

So should I go in for multiple callouts to display multiple strings or is there any way I can change the string content within a callout at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. It's like this:

this.callout.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "whatever text" };